# DataFrame and json after adding an extra level

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I have this dataframe
[image]

that I can convert to json with

```
> meanCorrel.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
```

> `'[{"delta":"0.1","ON":76.0129259415,"1W":77.0442672886,"2W":75.9245730576,"1M":75.7484174755,"2M":74.329029706,"3M":73.1859041159,"6M":71.7042759055,"9M":70.5581803962,"1Y":69.9258464061,"2Y":68.1257174971,"3Y":64.1039239267,"4Y":65.0152724347,"5Y":64.1346998629},{"delta":"-0.1","ON":75.8952295616,"1W":76.3491103861,"2W":75.8896971323,"1M":75.9670918897,"2M":75.1744201891,"3M":74.6580921073,"6M":73.8496683353,"9M":73.3132171538,"1Y":73.349414326,"2Y":73.2954307829,"3Y":69.9941526337,"4Y":67.2373993091,"5Y":65.3606791659},{"delta":"0.25","ON":76.738054934,"1W":77.8205026927,"2W":76.8616716183,"1M":76.93958601,"2M":75.7037450431,"3M":74.6161370503,"6M":72.9207639111,"9M":71.7854545179,"1Y":71.0329616424,"2Y":69.3345491289,"3Y":66.7008081619,"4Y":66.2882168583,"5Y":65.6895750039},{"delta":"-0.25","ON":77.1698342733,"1W":77.5808878599,"2W":77.0219111237,"1M":77.2683358976,"2M":76.4828903032,"3M":75.8632826443,"6M":74.8422769172,"9M":74.2654443604,"1Y":73.9721848439,"2Y":73.5619140753,"3Y":71.4498347269,"4Y":69.6876913636,"5Y":68.6501861265},{"delta":"0.0","ON":77.6184072533,"1W":78.2508197647,"2W":77.4905843992,"1M":77.6199049207,"2M":76.6744865553,"3M":75.8408616494,"6M":74.4715279455,"9M":73.686432304,"1Y":73.0726536521,"2Y":72.2220867094,"3Y":70.231312152,"4Y":69.0492020461,"5Y":68.4762664875}]'`

For every element of this array, I want to group the ON:..., 1W:..., .... under an object so that the results is

```
     "delta": 0.1,
      "myObj": {
        "ON": 76.012926,
        "1W": 77.044267,
       ...
      }
    },
    {
      "delta": -0.1,
      "myObj": {
        ...
      }
    },
   ...
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to achieve this, without having to manipulate the json itself, but by adding a level to the dataframe for e.g.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the options :
​

```
grp = meanCorrel.groupby(level=0, sort=False)
​
out = [{meanCorrel.index.name: float(v),
        "myObj": grp.get_group(v).squeeze().to_dict()} for v in grp.groups]
```

Output :

```
print(json.dumps(out, indent=2))

[
  {
    "delta": 0.1,
    "myObj": {
      "ON": 76.0129259415,
      "1W": 77.0442672886,
      "2W": 75.9245730576,
      "1M": 75.7484174755,
      "2M": 74.329029706,
      "3M": 73.1859041159,
      "6M": 71.7042759055,
      "9M": 70.5581803962,
      "1Y": 69.9258464061,
      "2Y": 68.1257174971,
      "3Y": 64.1039239267,
      "4Y": 65.0152724347,
      "5Y": 64.1346998629
    }
  },
  {
    "delta": -0.1,
    "myObj": {
      "ON": 75.8952295616,
      "1W": 76.3491103861,
      ...
```